# Openapi how to avoid anyOf showing Null for optional response

Tags: kotlin, openapi

I have openapi response schema like this

```
ProfileMetrics:
  description: List of metrics available in Field Profile
  type: object
  properties:
    fieldProfileMetrics:
      type: array
      items:
        type: object
    summaryProfileMetrics:
      type: array
      items:
        type: object
  anyOf:
    - required: [ fieldProfileMetrics ]
    - required: [ summaryProfileMetrics ]
```

Which results in a Response for example where I don't want fieldProfileMetrics in the Response.

```
{
  "fieldProfileMetrics": null,
  "summaryProfileMetrics": [
    {
      "name": "count_events",
      "description": "Number of rows/events in the dataset for particular timeframe",
      "subMetrics": []
    }]
}
```

So the response can be either `{fieldProfileMetric : SomeValue}` , `{summaryProfileMetric : SomeValue}` or `{fieldProfileMetric : SomeValue, summaryProfileMetric : SomeValue}`

The Service Class is like this

```
@Service
class ProfileMetricsService : ProfileMetricsApiService {

  override fun v1MetricsGet(profile: ProfileType?): ProfileMetrics {
    return when (profile) {
      ProfileType.field -> convertToProfileMetrics(profile, getFieldProfileMetrics())
      ProfileType.summary -> convertToProfileMetrics(
        profile, getSummaryProfileMetrics()
      )
      else -> convertToProfileMetrics(
        getFieldProfileMetrics(),
        getSummaryProfileMetrics()
      )
    }
  }

  private fun getFieldProfileMetrics(): MutableList<Map<String, Serializable>> {
    val fieldProfileList = mutableListOf<Map<String, Serializable>>()
    FieldProfileMetrics.values().forEach { it ->
      fieldProfileList.add(
        mapOf(
          Pair("name", it.value),
          Pair(FieldProfileMetrics::description.name, it.description),
          Pair(FieldProfileMetrics::subMetrics.name, it.subMetrics.map { it.value }.toTypedArray())
        )
      )
    }
    return fieldProfileList
  }

  private fun getSummaryProfileMetrics(): MutableList<Map<String, Serializable>> {
    val summaryProfileList = mutableListOf<Map<String, Serializable>>()
    SummaryProfileMetrics.values().forEach { profileMetric ->
      summaryProfileList.add(
        mapOf(
          Pair("name", profileMetric.value),
          Pair(SummaryProfileMetrics::description.name, profileMetric.description),
          Pair(SummaryProfileMetrics::subMetrics.name, profileMetric.subMetrics.map { it.value }.toTypedArray())
        )
      )
    }
    return summaryProfileList
  }

  private fun convertToProfileMetrics(
    profile: ProfileType,
    metricList: MutableList<Map<String, Serializable>>
  ): ProfileMetrics {
    return if (profile == ProfileType.field)
      ProfileMetrics(fieldProfileMetrics = metricList)
    else
      ProfileMetrics(summaryProfileMetrics = metricList)
  }

  private fun convertToProfileMetrics(
    fieldMetricList: MutableList<Map<String, Serializable>>,
    summaryMetricList: MutableList<Map<String, Serializable>>
  ): ProfileMetrics {
    return ProfileMetrics(
      fieldProfileMetrics = fieldMetricList,
      summaryProfileMetrics = summaryMetricList
    )
  }


  companion object {
    val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProfileMetricsService::class.java)
  }
}
```

The interface generated after generate-sources gives this

```
interface ProfileMetricsApiService {

    /**
     * GET /v1/metrics : Get list of field and summary profile metrics
     * Retrieves list of metrics for field and summary profile
     *
     * @param profile Profile Type (optional)
     * @return OK (status code 200)
     *         or Bad Request. (status code 400)
     *         or The specified resource was not found. (status code 404)
     *         or Unexpected error. (status code 200)
     * @see ProfileMetricsApi#v1MetricsGet
     */
    fun v1MetricsGet(profile: ProfileType?): ProfileMetrics
}
```

ProfileMetrics after compilation generates this

```
/**
 * List of metrics available in Field Profile
 * @param fieldProfileMetrics 
 * @param summaryProfileMetrics 
 */
data class ProfileMetrics(

    @field:Valid
    @Schema(example = "null", description = "")
    @field:JsonProperty("fieldProfileMetrics") val fieldProfileMetrics: kotlin.collections.List<kotlin.Any>? = null,

    @field:Valid
    @Schema(example = "null", description = "")
    @field:JsonProperty("summaryProfileMetrics") val summaryProfileMetrics: kotlin.collections.List<kotlin.Any>? = null
) {

}
```

This is how the response looks like [image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Where do you get the response with `null` from? Is it returned from your server-side implementation? If so, post your controller and class code and the related serialization code (if any).

Comment: @Helen I've added somethings, is there anything else needed or missing?